# Getting information for rest template

Tags: spring, rest

[image]

I have seen a lot of code that uses this `getForObject()` method that takes a URI and replaces things in `{}` with the numbers at the end of the method.

My question is: what exactly IS `http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/foos`? Is it a file of some sort? What would it look like in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example:

```
Foo foo = restTemplate.getForObject(URI, Foo.class, "1");
```

is actually trying to GET a REST resource with an HTTP request.

Under the covers:

1. The URL template is rendered to `http://localhost:8080/sping-rest/foos/1`
2. The HTTP client issues a GET request to `http://localhost:8080/sping-rest/foos/1`
3. The REST service can respond with a JSON representation of that resource, such as `{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}`
4. The HTTP client converts that JSON response into an instance of Foo.class (using message converters)
5. You get an instance of Foo!

The spring.io website [lists a lot of guides](https://spring.io/guides), you should definitely check them out! There's even a ["Consuming a RESTful web service"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) guide.